Using ReportViewer in .Net8 and .Net4.8
I am migrating my C# windows form application to .Net8 . Due to business needs
the application should target both .NetFramework 4.7.2 and .Net 8.0. I am getting below error
error CS0433: The type 'ReportViewer' exists in both 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.1.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
How can I resolve this.

"Due to business needs the application should target both .NetFramework 4.8 and .Net 8.0" What business need would require targetting both .NET Framework 4.x and .NET 8?

I have modified the Question , its 4.7.2 and 8.0 and we need to support legacy OS like windows 7 as well

Microsoft don't even support Windows 7 or 8.1 anymore.

Here's a great [article][1] that might help you
You can update your .csproj files like this
   <TargetFrameworks>net8.0;net472</TargetFrameworks>

Then if you have some issues with references you might add them using the conditions:
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net472' ">
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.12.0.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0' ">
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.15.1.19.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

That should help
[1]: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/target-multiple-frameworks-in-aspnet-core2
